# Как работает очищение экрана методом clear?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нашел на других сайтах сам код ,но не знаю как его использовать.
Приведите пожалуйста примеры программ там где есть такой метод.сам кусок ниже.

```
import curses
scrn = curses.initscr()
scrn.clear()
curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Уточните, в чём вопрос: как эта функция работает или зачем она нужна?

Comment: Мне не понятно как работает и как использовать(с чем,где)

Comment: Строго говоря, как она работает вас вообще не должно волновать (сложно она работает, в зависимости от типа терминала по-разному, интересно - см. исходники). А вот зачем нужно очищать область вывода - вопрос странный, я б даже сказал - с очевидным ответом... Либо я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: Я имею в виду мне не ясно где её вставлять-поэтому и нужны примеры)

Comment: Вставлять нужно там, где ВАМ захочется очистить область вывода. Ваш К.О.

Comment: если просто вставить где мне нужно то работать не будет

Comment: Создайте нормальный (новый) вопрос. В нём приведите код, который у вас не работает или работает неправильно (предварительно изучив страницу [mcve]). В такой постановке задачи как сейчас вам вряд ли кто-нибудь поможет.

Comment: `initscr()` не обязательно использовать. Посмотрите на Питон код, который команду `clear` реализует: [Python - Clearing the terminal screen more elegantly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34388390)

Answer (score 3):

В простом варианте посылается эскейп последовательность `"\033c"` ( `<ESC>+c` ) и терминал очищает буфер вывода на экран.

Comment: Это не совсем то что `initscr().clear()` делает, хотя тоже может работать (и более предпочтительно), но [действительная последовательность (`tput clear`)  может быть другой](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34388642/4279).